# ListView не обновляется после фильтрации

Tags: android, listview, android-search-view

```
private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        List<Etaloni> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        //filteredList.clear();
        if (constraint.toString().isEmpty()){
            filteredList.addAll(mProductListFull);
        }else {
            for (Etaloni movie : mProductListFull){
                if (movie.getEtaloni().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                    filteredList.add(movie);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        filterResults.values = filteredList;
        return filterResults;
    }
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        mProductList.clear(); //ეს კოდი - ფილტრაციის დროს შლის-არ აჩვენებს სხვა მონაცემებს
        mProductList.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: А как эта фильтрация выполняется?